# Import multiple variables to Gatsby component with TS and GraphQL Typegen

Tags: typescript, graphql, gatsby

```
  import { graphql } from 'gatsby';

  const Footer = ({phone}: { phone?: Queries.FooterFragment['phone'];}): JSX.Element => {
    return <footer>{phone}</footer>;
        };
  export default Footer

  export const query = graphql`
    fragment Footer on ContentfulBlockFooter {
      id
      name
      phone
    }`;
```

This is a component from a Gatsby project that uses TS and GraphQL Typegen, the document only shows how to import a single value from my Fragment, is there a clever way to "spread out" my Queries. In this case I want to have id, name and phone as component props without typing:

```
phone?: Queries.FooterFragment['phone'],
name?: Queries.FooterFragment['name'],
id?: Queries.FooterFragment['id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an `interface`?

```
interface FooterProps {
  phone?: Queries.FooterFragment['phone'],
  name?: Queries.FooterFragment['name'],
  id?: Queries.FooterFragment['id]
}
```

Then:

```
  const Footer = ({ phone }: FooterProps }): JSX.Element => {
    return <footer>{phone}</footer>;
  };
```

I'm not sure about the context but you may not need to use `Queries.FooterFragment` but using directly the type of each element:

```
interface FooterProps {
  phone?: string,
  name?: string,
  id?: string
}
```